# Render YouTube subscribe button after AJAX call success

Tags: javascript, ajax, youtube-javascript-api

How to render youTube subscribe button if is included inside AJAX response. I used the function below, that work but it returning this Error in console log :

```
SecurityError: Permission denied to access property "blablabla" on cross-origin object
```

```js
function load_js() {
  var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.type = 'text/javascript';
  script.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js';
  head.appendChild(script);
}

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: ajaURL,
  data: {
    action: 'my_action',
  },
  success: function(response) {
    // response = <div class="g-ytsubscribe" data-channelid="CHANNEL_ID" data-layout="default" data-count="default"></div>
    $('.youtube-btn-container').html(response);
    load_js();
  }
});
```

Comment: With what you have provided isn't of much help. *"Permission denied to access property 'blablabla'"* I see of no attempt to access any property, only to set the `html()` of an element with the response. Does `ajaURL` target youtube or a server-side file of your own?

Comment: ajax target server-side file

Comment: @NewToJS if I add the HTML "<div class="g-ytsubscribe" data-channelid="CHANNEL_ID" data-layout="default" data-count="default"></div>" without ajax it work and it returning no error. but with ajax I must to reload the platform.js file to work

Comment: A server-side file of your own and using the same domain? Your question is lacking very important information which is making it very hard to help you so please update your question and include all relevant information.

Comment: @NewToJS I used the method gapi.ytsubscribe.render. Here full example : https://developers.google.com/youtube/subscribe/reference?hl=en#Dynamic_Rendering_Example_render

Answer (score 0):

If you're testing this locally, you might need to **allow cross origin resource sharing** (CORS). It's a header that ought to present in your request. You can read more about it over at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS).

In Chrome, there are several extensions that make this easy. I personally use [this](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en) one.

Comment: I used another method, that work with no error (gapi.ytsubscribe.render). Here full example : https://developers.google.com/youtube/subscribe/reference?hl=en#Dynamic_Rendering_Example_render